# How to designed a correct MVC on iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, model-view-controller

I have a project where I want to display overlays to locate people on a map. I have difficulties to follow the MVC pattern since I've never practice it.

In a database, I'll save a position (in map coordinates) and the image to identify one person (the image of the overlay).

If 2 or more are at the same position, they are grouped under another "group" overlay. When an overlay is touched, I want to display different information, depending of its type ("group" or "single").

Here is my problem : I obviously need to subclass an `Overlay` superclass, which have the properties position and image, to redefined the `overlayTouched:` method. But this code his typically a View code of the MVC pattern, but the overlay is a Model object since it will be saved, so i'm confused.

How should I designed this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not subclass `Overlay` to add touch events to it, instead create a new `UIView`, `YourNewView`

This `YourNewView` will "has a" instance of `Overlay`, and it will delegate all its method that are required from the model to `Overlay`

For example. if you have a `touchesEnded` in your `YourNewView` and you want it to save the overlay to the DB, you would do

```
//in touchesEnded
[self.overlay saveToDb];
```

And so on, all the calls will be forwarded to the `Overlay` Class

Comment: ok, but how can I redefined the touchesEnded depending on the overlay's type ?

The View has direct access to the Model, we should avoid that to stick to the MVC, no ?

Comment: you would switch it over some propery in the overlay.someproperty

Comment: Finally, I made an Overlay class with the image and the position, an OverlayView to display it, and an OverlayController to link them and handle the click. IMO, that fits the MVC pattern, don't you think ?

Comment: Yes, but you will have to make a destination between the overlay and overlay view, overlay must never draw itself

Comment: Yes, that's what I've done, the OverlayView is here to perform the drawing, Overlay is pure Model. Thanks you.